# prove that $\langle S \rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups containing $S$

Tags: group-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of $G$, where $G$ is a group. I have to prove that the generated of $S$ is the intersection of all subgroups which contain $S$. I have been thinking about this for a while, but it seems I cant find a way of proving it. I really need hints! Thank you.

Comment: How have you had the subgroup generated by $S$ defined?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As how wikipedia does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group

Comment: In that article it says "intersection of all subgroups containing $S$" among other things. Which part do you mean?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I actually mean: <S> is the set wich contains all finite products of elements in S under the group operation.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried? Have you shown if $H$ is a subgroup containing $S$ then $H$ contains the subgroup generated by $S$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, I have already shown that.

Comment: Ok, so what part are you stuck on?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have proved the inclusion that the intersection of all subgroups containing S contains <S>. So now I have to prove the other inclusion, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Show that the subgroup generated by $S$ is indeed a subgroup containing $S$, so it is one of the subgroups you take the intersection over (and hence that intersection is contained in it).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft but I actually used this to prove that <S> is contained in the intersection. or maybe I dont understand you.

Comment: Try writing up what you have done so far in detail, so we can see.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh I see what I was doing wrong, thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = \{H \le G| S \subset H \}$. Note that $G \in A$, therefore $A \neq \phi$ and $S' := \cap_{H \in A} H$ is well defined. We will now prove both the inclusions $S' \subset \langle S\rangle $ and $\langle S\rangle \ \subset S'$.

By definition, the generated by $S$ is the smallest subgroup which contains $S$: this implies that $\langle S\rangle  \in A$ therefore $S' \subset \langle S\rangle $. The other inclusion follows the fact that if we suppose $\langle S\rangle  \nsubseteq S'$ then $\langle S\rangle  \cap \ S'$ contradicts the minimality of $\langle S\rangle $.