# If $H$ is the intersection of all subgroups that contains a subset $S$ of a group, then $\langle S \rangle=H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem:** Let $S$ be a subset of a group and let $H$ be the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contains $S$. Prove that $\langle S \rangle=H$.

**My thoughts:** As my goal is to prove $\langle S \rangle=H$ and both are sets, so I can reach my goal by showing $\langle S \rangle \subseteq H$ and $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$.

**My attempt:** Let $A:= \{K ≤G| S \subseteq K\}$ and $H:= ∩_{K \in A}K$. Since $S \subseteq K$ for all $K \in A$, thus $S  \subseteq H$. This shows $\langle S \rangle \subseteq H$. Now we want to show $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$ and here i stuck!

**My confusion**:
I got a solution [prove that $\langle S \rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups containing $S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/336080/1048756) . Here I don't understand that if $\langle S \rangle \in A$, then how $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$?

Comment: What is your definition of $\langle S \rangle$? Most people would define $\langle S \rangle$ to be the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$.

Comment: @IrvingRabin Let $S$ be any collection of elements froma group. Then $\langle S \rangle$ is defined as the subgroup of group with the property that $\langle S \rangle$ contains $S$ and if $H$ is any subgroup of group containing $S$, then $H$ also contains $\langle S \rangle$. Author defines the notion like this.

Comment: In tour attempt: It's not $S\in\langle S\rangle$, but $S\subseteq\langle S\rangle$. Then, given that $S\subseteq K$, for every $K \in A$, it follows that $S\subseteq\bigcap_{K\in A}K$. Is that not clear?

Comment: @amrsa Till here everything is clear. But how $S ⊆ ∩_{K ∈A)K $  implies that   $⟨ S ⟩⊆ ∩_{K ∈A}K$ ?

Comment: @MuhammadAfzalSoomro I'll refer you to Irving's answer: prove that the intersection of all subgroups containing $S$ is a subgroup containing $S$ (and notice that $\langle S\rangle \in A$, by definition of $A$ and $\langle S\rangle$).

Comment: @amrsa Ok. I have proved that intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$ contain $S$.Now i am confused how this shows that $H ⊆ ⟨S ⟩$.  On the other hand I know $ ⟨S ⟩$ is the smallest subgroup containing $S$ so $⟨S ⟩ ⊆ H$

Comment: @MuhammadAfzalSoomro Basically, I agree with Irving's answer (the upvote was mine). That answer was submitted 16 seconds after my comment; otherwise I'd think there were nothing more to say, and wouldn't have posted the comment. I think the answer is clear enough, and perhaps you should accept it (and maybe upvote it).

Comment: @amrsa I understood Irving's completely. Actually I missed a basic point that, if $ ⟨S ⟩$ is in $A$, then $H ⊆ ⟨S ⟩$ follows since $H$ is the intersection of all subgroups containing $S$ and including $ ⟨S ⟩$. I really didn't think about $A ∩B ⊆A$ and $A ∩B ⊆B$ instead of this i was thinking completely in wrong direction. Thats why i asked question again and again. Btw everything is clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** To show $\langle S \rangle \subseteq H$, you need to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. To do so, show that the intersection of subgroups is again a subgroup. To see that $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$, note that $H$ is the intersection of *all subgroups* of $G$ containing $S$, and that $\langle S \rangle$ is one such subgroup.

**Edit:**
You write in your comment to amrsa that you have shown that the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$ *contains S*. This is true, but not what you need here. Show that for an arbitrary collection $\{K_i\}$ of subgroups of $G$, their intersection $\bigcap_{i \in I} K_i$ is a subgroup of $G$.

For $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$, if you sit with the definition of $H$ for a bit, you should see that $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$ is immediate. Think of the case where we have two sets, it's certainly true that
$$
A \cap B \subseteq A \text{ and } A \cap B \subseteq B.
$$
If $H$ is the intersection of all subgroups containing $S$ and $\langle S \rangle$ is one such subgroup, then it must be that $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$.

If you want the proof completely in your notation. Let $A = \{K \leq G \mid S \subseteq K\}$, then $H = \cap_{K \in A} K$. As amrsa mentioned, notice that $\langle S \rangle \in A$ and as such $H \subseteq \langle S \rangle$ is immediate because $\langle S \rangle$ is an element of the intersection defining $H$.

Comment: For $H⊆⟨S⟩$. Do you mean $[∀x(x∈S→x∈H)→∀x(x ∈S→x ∈ ⟨S⟩]$?      
 If so, then why there is implication between $S ⊆H$ and $S ⊆ ⟨S⟩$?

Comment: Edited my response for more elaboration @MuhammadAfzalSoomro.

Comment: Oh I understood now everything. I missed to think about $A ∩B ⊆A$ and $A ∩ B ⊆B$. I was thinking totally in wrong direction. How dumb I am. Thank you for making everything clear.